# Error: Cannot find module '/Applications/Atom.app/***/electron.asar/browser/init.js' while attaching debugger to nodejs

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I'm trying to debug my node script using atom-node-debugger plugin.

Below are the commands I used to start the node script -

[image]

When I try to attach the debugger I am getting below error -

```
    throw err;

    Error: Cannot find module '/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Frameworks/Atom Helper.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:683:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:196:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:622:3
    Process exited (Port: 9229 (Node attach))
```

How can I resolve this error?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, that file does not exist. In the most recent version of Atom (1.38.x at the time of this writing), the file `electron.asar` is located at `Atom.app/Contents/Resources`, but not inside the `Atom Helper.app`.

There are [several issues](https://github.com/kiddkai/atom-node-debugger/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=electron.asar) open on GitHub with a *similar* error. Looks like the package is outdated and no longer actively maintained.